# Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found error in SPFX

Tags: spfx, angular2

I am trying to use angular 4 in SharePoint Framework. Basic setup is done but when I try to use angular command `ng g service app` it throws error `Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.`

I have found few solution of it on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810580/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found

Does it work the same way in spfx also?